# How to install WinGHCi?

Tags: haskell, winghci

I used to learn Haskell before I uninstalled everything. Now, I downloaded the Haskell platform but it seems there's no WinGHCi. Any suggestion please to solve the issue?
I tried to install it manually but there is no .exe file.

Comment: Please be specific about what exactly you “tried to install manually”. And note that the most common way to install Haskell is nowadays [Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/).

Comment: this one https://youtu.be/Uva-sysnrEQ?list=PLmTgnNwroyn8TnF26YRvW-hvQF1ypztzg&t=181

Comment: Ok, add this information to the question itself, don't just link to it.

Comment: Thank you for your time bro. I will use replit

Comment: Click and download: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_9_0_1.html#windows64 :D